# Why docker container iptables permission denied?

Tags: docker, iptables

I run docker container by docker-compose.yml file.

Below he setting for the container in problem.

```yaml
test:
    image: captainteemo/aips:1.0
    container_name: test
    hostname: test
    volumes:
      - /home/{{.Node.Hostname}}/share/hosts:/etc/hosts
      - /home/{{.Node.Hostname}}/share/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64
    environment:
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    tty: true
    command: /sbin/init
    ports:
      - 8128:8128
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == user1
```

The binding port is a port for back-end server access.

However, when running a backend server using uvicorn, access is not possible. Also, if i check the port with 'netstat', the 8128 port is not confirmed.

So after installing the 'iptables' package, I tried to open the port with the 'iptables -I INPUT 1-ptcp --dport 8128-j ACCEPT' command, but I get the same error as below.

```bash
iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I tried to search this error and solution, but never is worked...

How can I solve it???

ADD. I start server by command by

```bash
uvicorn main:app --reload --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8128
```

but when I checked netstat, below result:

```bash
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:33727        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

ADD.
If I run server in 'user1' docker node, Below is print and stucked:

```bash
INFO: Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/home/zioz/server_place/test_web'] 
INFO: Uvicorn running on 0.0.0.0:8128 (Press CTRL+C to quit) 
INFO: Started reloader process [531] using StatReload
```

If I run server in other(leader) docker node, Below is print and run well:

```bash
INFO: Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/home/zioz/server_place/test_web'] 
INFO: Uvicorn running on 0.0.0.0:8128 (Press CTRL+C to quit) 
INFO: Started reloader process [531] using StatReload
INFO: Started server process [429] 
INFO: Waiting for application startup. 
INFO: Application startup complete.
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to directly use `iptables`.  What URL are you trying to connect to, and what error are you getting?  What's actually happening in the container?  Overriding the image's command to run an unqualified `init` is a little unusual; what is in the original Dockerfile, and why do you need to inject a host JVM?

Comment: I tried to start B/E server by FastAPI. But when I run server through uvicorn, port(8128) is not open. Then I can't API test to "test" container's B/E server.

Comment: Your `entrypoint:` line is overriding the Dockerfile – if you had set `CMD uvicorn ...` in the Dockerfile, that isn't getting run.  What is in the Dockerfile, what URL are you actually connecting to, and what errors do you get?  (The `netstat` output is less interesting than knowing what the results of an actual connection attempt are.)

Comment: If I place the test container on the user1 docker node and run the server, below will be printed and the server will not run. 
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/home/zioz/server_place/test_web']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8128 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [531] using StatReload

Comment: However, if I place the test container on the user2 docker node and run the server, below is printed and the server runs well. INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/home/zioz/server_place/test_web']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8128 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [427] using StatReload INFO:     Started server process [429]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.